# pass value other than 0 - 1 in circularProgressIndicator Flutter

Tags: flutter

So I'm creating an app that allows to download some file. I manage to track the progress of the current download number (0 until 100). I want my CircularProgressIndicator to be determinate how can I achieve that ? so when the progress variable reach 100 the circularProgressIndicator should show full circle also.

Here's my current code:

```
late AnimationController circularProgressController;

    circularProgressController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: progress),
    )..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });

    CircularProgressIndicator(
        value: circularProgressController.value,
        strokeWidth: 2.0,
        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(floatingActionButtonColor),
    ),
```

Comment: you need to call `forward` method on your animation controller

Comment: Use this library , I think it will meet your requirements https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator